# Inkscape: clip imported raster just inside colored line

Tags: inkscape, path, clipping-mask, raster, image-trace

here's a map of a country with a red border:
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/13/Congo_Kinshasa_Topography.png

i've imported the .png and now want to clip it to just show what's inside the red border.

tracing results in a huge complicated mess of paths and nodes that basically cause inkscape to hang when i try to intersect/difference them with pencil-drawn paths to try to isolate the border.

i feel like i must not be approaching this correctly, what's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Hi there and welcome to GDSE.

As you might know the image you have is a *raster* image which consists of pixels.

Inkscape is a *vector* drawing application. You can place/import raster images, but you can't directly manipulate the pixels.

As you have experienced your image is way to complicated to do an automated trace.

I recommend you to do one of the following:

1. Open the image in a raster image application (Photoshop, GIMP etc.) and erase/mask the unwanted area manually (there are many different ways to do this).
2. Use Inkscape to manually trace the contour using *pen tool* and then use this shape as a *clipping mask* for the image.
3. Find another similar image in *svg* format (which is a vector based format). Open it in Inkscape and delete the unwanted paths.

Comment: the image isn't too complicated for a trace, see my answer.  i just had to experiment with the trace options a bit.

Answer (score 1):

The red border is part of the PNG. It's not a vector, so you can't use it as a clipping mask. It's not possible. Inkscape is a vector image editor.

However it is possible to add a vector clipping mask to a raster image in Inkscape. But the process is manual, and involves drawing the clipping mask manually.

- Create a closed path with the Bézier tool, around the area you wish to clip.
- Select both the path and raster image
- Click *Object > Clip > Set*

Here's a quick example. I have drawn a closed shape filled with semi-transparent orange so you can see it. I select both the raster and the path, then clip it.

[image]

Comment: i want an *exact* clip, as automated as possible.  see my answer, it is possible, i just had to understand trace options a little better.

Answer (score 1):

a color multi scan trace isolates the red (i used 24 colors but i think you could use less). i found the red one, moved it to another layer, and deleted the rest. then i broke it apart, found the resulting path for the contiguous border, moved it to another layer, and deleted the rest. since the border isn't a closed path (there's a little opening at the coastline), i then had to use the pencil tool, path intersection/difference operations, and another break apart, etc, to get rid of extraneous nodes. then a linked offset, edited its radius to -0.5 in xml editor, and i had a perfect clip.

Comment: this stack exchange requires me to wait to accept this answer, but as far as i know this is the most exact and automated method.

Answer (score 0):

On the [page](https://als.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demokratische_Republik_Kongo), where your PNG can be found, there is a SVG file too, two pictures above.

I would download this one, and see, whether the details are fine enough for my needs.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm interested in keeping the topography information in the png